# Using boost::bind and boost::lambda::new_ptr to return a shared_ptr constructor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

Given a class A,

```
class A {
 public:
  A(B&) {}
};
```

I need a `boost::function<boost::shared_ptr<A>(B&)>` object.

I prefer not to create an ad-hoc function

```
boost::shared_ptr<A> foo(B& b) {
  return boost::shared_ptr<A>(new A(b));
}
```

to solve my problem, and I'm trying to solve it binding lambda::new_ptr.

```
boost::function<boost::shared_ptr<A> (B&)> myFun
= boost::bind(
    boost::type<boost::shared_ptr<A> >(),
    boost::lambda::constructor<boost::shared_ptr<A> >(),
    boost::bind(
      boost::type<A*>(),
      boost::lambda::new_ptr<A>(),
      _1));
```

that is, I bind in two steps the new_ptr of a A and the constructor of shared_ptr. Obviously it doesn't work:

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:236: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::lambda::constructor<boost::shared_ptr<A> >) (A*)’
/usr/include/boost/lambda/construct.hpp:28: note: candidates are: T boost::lambda::constructor<T>::operator()() const [with T = boost::shared_ptr<A>]
/usr/include/boost/lambda/construct.hpp:33: note:                 T boost::lambda::constructor<T>::operator()(A1&) const [with A1 = A*, T = boost::shared_ptr<A>]
```

How should I do the binding instead?
Thanks in advance,
Francesco

Comment: This is a perfect example of how lambdas actually make the whole thing unnecessarily more complicated for no added benefits other than added compile times. C++'s limit probably been pushed too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `boost::lambda::bind` instead of `boost::bind`.

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp> // !
#include <boost/lambda/construct.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

void test()
{
  using namespace boost::lambda;
  boost::function<boost::shared_ptr<A>(B&)> func = 
    bind( constructor< boost::shared_ptr<A> >(), bind( new_ptr<A>(), _1 ) );
}
```